# Spring boot 3.0 + Spring security 6 + 2 different auth server for different URL access

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I have implemented authorization code flow in my spring boot application. Having a keyclock as auth server. After I logged in the application and when I when click on another link I require again to initiate auth code flow with another instant of keyclock and get access token. Can someone suggest how can we configure two different auth server. Like we can configure to different data source in a spring boot application.

For example when I try to access a URL localhost:8080/index It will redirect to one of the keyclock
And if I click another link with URL localhost:8080/product It will redirect to another keyclock.